# Can I update my cover letter for a job I've applied for?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I recently applied for a job on StackOverflow jobs. After applying, I realized I could have done a better job with the cover letter. When I go back to the job -- is there a way to update it? I didn't see one.

Answer (score 2):

Once you apply to a job, there is no way to go back and update your cover letter or resume.